# Trying to get data from a number of consecutive dates

Tags: swift, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm trying to build an array of data from 3000 consecutive days but the code will only extract data from one single date 3000 times. 
When I print the date that I keep increasing (`theincreasingnumberofdays`) I can see that it is adding one day to the date every time it loops, but when I read out the Array after the loop it's all the same data 3000 times.

```
class day
{
var week: Int?
var date: Int?
var month: Int?
var year: Int?
var weekday: Int?
}


@IBAction func pressbuttontodefinearray(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("button has been pressed")

    if (theArrayContainingAllTheUserData.count > 1) {
        print("array contains something allready and we don't do anything")
        return
    }

    print("array is empty and we're filling it right now")
    var ScoopDay =  day()

    var numberofloops = 0

    while theArrayContainingAllTheUserData.count < 3000
    {
        var theincreasingnumberofdays: NSDate {
            return NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: numberofloops, to: NSDate() as Date)! as NSDate
        }

        print(theincreasingnumberofdays)

        let myCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!

        // var thenextdate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: numberofloops, to: date as Date)
        numberofloops=numberofloops+1
        ScoopDay.week=Int(myCalendar.component(.weekday, from: theincreasingnumberofdays as Date!))
        ScoopDay.date=Int(myCalendar.component(.day, from: theincreasingnumberofdays as Date!))
        ScoopDay.month=Int(myCalendar.component(.month, from: theincreasingnumberofdays as Date!))
        ScoopDay.year=Int(myCalendar.component(.year, from: theincreasingnumberofdays as Date!))
        ScoopDay.weekday=Int(myCalendar.component(.weekday, from: theincreasingnumberofdays as Date!))

        theArrayContainingAllTheUserData.append(ScoopDay)
    }

    print("we're done with this looping business. Let's print it")
    var placeinarray = 0
    while placeinarray < 2998
    {
        print("Here is", placeinarray, theArrayContainingAllTheUserData[placeinarray].date, theArrayContainingAllTheUserData[placeinarray].month)
        placeinarray=placeinarray+1
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: Side-note: Your loop is very expensive. For example you're creating 3000 calendar instances of the same type and all received components are `Int` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is one `day` object, named `ScoopDay`, and you are adding that one object to the array 3000 times. So the array ends up with 3000 references to that one single object, which contains the last values you assigned to it.

You can fix this by moving the line

```
var ScoopDay =  day()
```

inside the loop. That way you will create 3000 different `day` objects, each with different contents.

A Swift style tip: capitalize the first letter of class names, and lowercase the first letter of variable names, so:

```
class Day
```

and

```
var scoopDay =  Day()
```

Comment: You, sir are a godsend! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! If it answers your question, please mark the question as answered -- thanks!